# Default Height of ProgressIndicator

Tags: windows-phone-8

I simply just need to find a way to determine the height of `ProgressIndicator` in my WP8 Silverlight solution. I know how to set the height, but I would just like to retrieve the height. This would be done in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ActualHeight` property to retrieve the height of your control:

```
var height = this.ProgressIndicator.ActualHeight;
```

Note that the property will be filled only after the page has finished loading (more precisely, after the layout is computed)

Comment: Thanks. The height is 4 px for anyone's quick reference (in WP8 Silverlight)